# How to resize image in UIView?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to set image into UIView but I can't resize it in my view I got something like this:

[UIview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqy3I.png)

```
     let imageName = "rectanguloAzul"
     let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
     let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
     imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
     self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: I would also recommend you elaborate a bit more about the problem you are facing and what end results are you trying to achieve.
So an example would be:
"By using the following code I managed to add the image to the view but the size is not the size I want. How do I change the image to fit the view?"

By writing it the way you wrote it you leave too much for interpretation :) 
Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome.
You need to either give the imageView a frame or use Autolayout to set a layout for the image inside the UIView.

so either add this at the end:

```
imageView.frame = view.frame
```

But this will not be dynamic and you should learn how to keep updating the frame whenever the superview's frame changes.

Or you can add this, instead:

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let constraints = [
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

Anyway, I really recommend you read up about AutoLayout a bit before you continue:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html
https://www.raywenderlich.com/811496-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-getting-started

If you find programmatic AutoLayout to be too challenging, I would recommend possibly starting with Storyboards first.